# How to install renamed Tycho product into maven repository

Tags: maven-3, tycho

I tried to use the new Tycho feature for renaming the produced artifact.
The zip files are renamed correctly under the target/products directory, but when Maven installs them to C:\.m2, they will have the original name.

```
<configuration>
    <products>
        <product>
            <id>my.product.id</id>
            <archiveFileName>xyz</archiveFileName>
        </product>
    </products> 
</configuration>
```

Result in target/products directory: `xyz-win32.win32.x86.zip`

Result in C:\.m2...\: `my.product.id-win32.win32.x86.zip`

Is there another place to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of thinking, I have the solution, that there is no solution.
It's not possible to rename the artifact in the maven repository. How would maven find the artifact in case of a renamed zip file.

The only place to rename the zip file is in the target directory and work on from this place.